# simpleXml to array behaviour looks strange to me and - breaks at 9941 items

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

EDIT3: It seems that the problem occurs on my localhost XAMPP PHP 5.3 setup, not on any of the remote servers running php 5.2 that I've tested. Still unclear if its php or xampp (or maybe the combination) that causes the error /EDIT3

I have an xml with about 12000 names to add to an array.
The xml structure looks like this:

```
<smdusersync datetime="2010-12-13 13:51:16">
  <userstoadd>
    <User fnamn="Adam" enamn="Svensson" email="adam@darkeye.se" password="3906" />
    <User fnamn="Brooke" enamn="Jarnbjer" email="brooke@gmail.com" password="2729" />
    <User fnamn="Caesar" enamn="Carlsson" email="caesar@comhem.se" password="1668" />
   <!-- about 12000 other users -->
  </userstoadd>
  <userstoremove>
  </userstoremove>
</smdusersync>
```

EDIT2: I've tried with other xml examples, including programmatically generated with no attbutes etc, and that doesn't matter - still the same problem described below... /EDIT2

When running a simple foreach loop on the xml userstoadd child, strange things start to
happen when I push objects to an array.

(Please note that the example below has the code that causes the error - it's not a useful example in any way...)

Running a simple foreach loop (here just pushing a testcounter to the array) works as expected:

```
    $user_xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
    $xml_count = $user_xml->userstoadd->children()->count();
    $users_arr = array();
    $test_count = 0;
    foreach ($user_xml->userstoadd->children() as $user) {

        array_push($users_arr, $test_count); // << Works as expected!
        $test_count++;
    }
    echo $xml_count, '/', $test_count;
```

The $xml_count and $test_count always have the same value.

When I do the same, except for that I push a simple object to the array, everything works fine if the number of xml users <= 9940:

```
    $user_xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
    $xml_count = $user_xml->userstoadd->children()->count();
    $users_arr = array();
    $test_count = 0;
    foreach ($user_xml->userstoadd->children() as $user) {
        $dummy_object = new StdClass();  // << Empty dummy object
        array_push($users_arr, $dummy_object); // << CAUSES ERROR if more than 9940 items...!
        $test_count++;
    }
    echo $xml_count, '/', $test_count; // << SHOULD BE THE SAME!
```

When having 9940 xml user items, the output is as expected **9940/9940**.
BUT when having 9941 xml user items, the output is **9941/19881**!
And when having 9942 xml user items, the output is 9942/19882!

Suddenly almost 10000 difference! And the content of the user items doesn't seem to matter... I've copied and moved xml user items with the same result...

EDIT: When more than 9940 items, it suddeny doubles so that 9941 items give (9940 x 2) + 1 = 19881. 
No difference when using one single xml user item 12000 times. /EDIT

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is your xml valid? Sounds like a fault in there.

Comment: Hmm... It couldn't be a coincidence that 9940 x 2 = 19880... But that doesn't explain anything to me..!

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you give it an XML file which has the exact same structure copied and pasted 12k times?

Comment: Hi Mark and thirtydot! As far as I've tried, there seems to be not difference when using the same tag...

Comment: Just replaced the different tags with a copy of one single valid tag, and it breaks at the same spot. 9940 ok, 9941 gives error...

Comment: That makes it easier for us to test with the "same" file then.

Comment: "CAUSES ERROR if more than 9940 items...!", what error?

Comment: As I write, it suddenly doubles the number of array-items.

Comment: Isolate the problem and write a UnitTest

Comment: I've tried now with a synthesized xml <root><items><item id="0" /><item id="1"> (10000 items...) </items></root> with no difference, except that it breaks at 9939 opposed to 9940...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following insanity solves the problem for me:

You might want to comment out the `test(50000);` line.

```
<?php

test(9996); // works                         (echoes 9996/9996/9996)
test(9997); // BREAKS on my XAMPP php 5.3.1! (echoes 9997/19993/19993)
test(50000); // test with larger number

function test($items_to_create) {
    $xml_str = '<root>' . chr(13);
    for($i=0; $i<$items_to_create; $i++) {
        $xml_str .= '<item attr="t' . $i . '"/>' . chr(13);
    }
    $xml_str .= '</root>';

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);

    $xml_children = $xml->children();
    $xml_count = $xml_children->count();
    $arr = array();
    $test_count = 0;

    /*
    foreach ($xml->children() as $user) {
        $dummy_object = new StdClass();
        array_push($arr, $dummy_object);
        $test_count++;
    }
    */

    for ($i=0; $i<$xml_count; $i++) {
        $dummy_object = new StdClass();
        $dummy_object->foo = $xml_children[$i]->attributes()->attr;
        array_push($arr, $dummy_object);
        $test_count++;
    }


    $arr_count = count($arr);
    echo '<br />CTRL+F for me:', $xml_count, '/', $test_count , '/', $arr_count, '<hr />';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($arr, true), '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Does it fix it for you?

Comment: Yep, that works! Thank you, thirtydot! Still very strange... I will try to find out if it's related to php 5.3 and/or XAMPP...

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it I can't see any relation to XML handling. Please run this code to verify:

```
$xml_count = 9950;
$users_arr = array();
$test_count = 0;
foreach (range(0, $xml_count) as $user) {
    $dummy_object = new StdClass();
    array_push($users_arr, $dummy_object);
    $test_count++;
}
echo $xml_count, '/', $test_count, '/', count($users_arr);
```

It should print the number 9950 three times. If that's not the case on your machine, your PHP is broken.

Comment: Thank you, rik! Your code gives the expected result, no problem here. I've done a similar test using xml, and that then I get the error. But I've located the problem somehow related to my XAMPP php 5.3 setup...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've isolated the as somhow related to my XAMPP php 5.3 setup. 
Test on two different remote servers with php 5.2 and there it works as expected.

The following code breaks on my XAMPP with php 5.3.1

```
<?php
test(9996); // works                         (echoes 9996/9996/9996)
test(9997); // BREAKS on my XAMPP php 5.3.1! (echoes 9997/19993/19993)

function test($items_to_create) {
    $xml_str = '<root>' . chr(13);
    for($i=0; $i<$items_to_create; $i++) {
        $xml_str .= '<item />' . chr(13);
    }
    $xml_str .= '</root>';

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);

    $xml_count = $xml->children()->count();
    $arr = array();
    $test_count = 0;
    foreach ($xml->children() as $user) {
        $dummy_object = new StdClass();
        array_push($arr, $dummy_object);
        $test_count++;
    }
    $arr_count = count($arr);
    echo "<br/>", $xml_count, '/', $test_count , '/', $arr_count;
}
```

Comment: I can recreate this: "9996/9996/9996 9997/19993/19993". I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: @thirtydot: What php version are you using? Localhost with XAMPP or other setup?

Comment: I downloaded XAMPP 1.7.3 to test this problem locally.